# Why can I (and a lot of people) access my website normally but some users can't?

Tags: iis, dns

I bought my domain name and registered it with ASmallOrange.

Next, I bought a VPS server with SoftSysHosting.

I went on the CPanel of ASmall orange and set the domains to point to my server's IP address:

[image]

After half a day or so, the DNS record propagated to my machine and I could access the website using the domain name. A so could everybody else.

However today, someone told me they could not access my site, and checking it with http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ told me the same results:

> It's not just you! FOO.BAR looks down from here.

Yet I can still access my site.

Is it safe to assume that the DNS record hasn't reached certain areas yet? It's been almost three days now and I find that hard to believe.

On my VPS, I only have IIS with SQL Server. **I did not install anything related to DNS.**

Comment: I use the same provider and personally had to wait two weeks before my domain name resolved. (It had a weird TLD, though, so yours will probably take much less time.)

Comment: @minitech what is "a weird TLD"? .xxx?

Comment: I think this shouldn't be tagged as SQL Server and should probably be moved to ServerFault (or webmasters I guess makes even more sense).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: `.ch` for `minite.ch` :)

Answer (score 1):

While ISPs and other providers are supposed to obey the TTL set by your nameserver, not all will. You should check with your host and see what your actual TTL is set to, as it may be longer than you think. I remember often having to wait up to 48 hours for DNS changes to propagate, but if your TTL is longer (or you are looking at some naughty-behaving providers) then it would explain the behavior.